# Using SSH Keys with IP*Works

Tags: c#, ssh

I try to connect to an SSH server with nsoftware's IP*Works components without password. The only information about the components' capability is described in the following document:

http://www.nsoftware.com/kb/help/BWN1-A/Type_Certificate.rst

I have created keys with Putty, which is a PPK file as:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: aes256-cbc
Comment: rsa-key-20130329
Public-Lines: 4
...
Private-Lines: 8
...
Private-MAC: ...
```

However any tries to open this file with nsoftware.IPWorksSSH.Certificate fails. Does anybody have an experience with the Certificate object of Ip*works?

Comment: Putty's keygen program should be able to export the key in the standard openssh format.  Very few programs use the putty format (the ones that do mostly are using the putty executable internally)

Comment: I'm also failing to see how that documentation page is in any way related to ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, IP*Works does not use the same key format as PuTTY.  You will need to convert the key.  This is documented here:

- [Are .ppk files supported?](http://www.nsoftware.com/kb/showentry.aspx?entry=06120702)